# Global variable accessed inside pre-defined function returns null - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, scope

For some reason, I can't access a variable. Might be a scope issue, or timing issue, can't find it out. Here's my simplified code:

```
var endResult = "";

//function loads html into given element.Called as a callback later when google maps direction service is done//
function getResults(){
  $.ajax({
    url:'foo.php',
    data: endResult,
    //etc., response loaded asynchronously in div element//
  });
}

//when form is submitted
$('#form').submit(function(){
  var endResult = "";
  //get form data, define variable//
  $.post('bar.php',function(data){
    var location = data;
    //initialize Maps Directions Service//
    var directionService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    //function gets directions, and loads a single value into global variable "endResult"//
    function calcRoute(){
      var request = {//google maps arguments containing form data//};
      directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
        var endResult = JSON.stringify(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value);  
        console.log(endResult); //Outputs intended value from google maps//
        //run function as a callback making sure that "endResult" is not null//
        getResults(); //iside this function - value of "endResult" is null, data sent to foo.php is null//
      });
    }
    calcRoute();
  }
  return false;
});
```

That's it, once I call getResults(), inside that function, endResult will be null. I'm sure it's something simple, but I can't get my head around it.

Comment: declare endResult only first time globally.. after that you don't need to write "var" because you declare it everytime new.

Comment: You seem to have the habit of using `var` any time you're assigning a value to a variable. `var` *declares* a variable. You don't use it when you assign to an existing variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not assigning to the global variable, because you have

```
    var endResult = "";
//  ^^^
```

in the submit handler, and

```
    var endResult = JSON.stringify(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value);
//  ^^^
```

...in `calcRoute`.

Those declare **local** variables in those functions, which shadow the global (and the one in `calcRoute` shadows the one in the submit handler).

Just remove those `var`s, so you're assigning to the variable that code closes over (the global).

---

In general, avoid using truly global variables, and minimize the degree to which functions have side effects (like assigning to and reading from variables they close over). In this case, rather than having `endResult` be a global, there's no reason `calcRoute` can't pass it to `getResults` as an argument.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, it works now. I feel a bit stupid, but that's how we learn after all. Thanks, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You should pass that variable in that function as an argument.

```
getResults(endResult);
```

You should avoid using `var` inside the form submit function. If you do so, it will be declared again as a local variable and will be limited to that function's scope.

Comment: Probably, but it doesn't answer the question of why the global isn't set.

Comment: When you use the variable with `var` again, then it will get declared again and then it won't be global variable anymore.